# Go module "invalid revision" when dependency using vendored dependency

Tags: go, go-modules, kuma

I am trying to import https://github.com/kumahq/kuma in my project. Kuma project has a vendored dependency and following contents are present in its go.mod:

```
replace github.com/prometheus/prometheus => ./vendored/github.com/prometheus/prometheus
```

When I run `go mod download` or `go list -m` in my project I am getting the following error:

```
github.com/prometheus/prometheus@v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000: invalid version: unknown revision 000000000000
```

I don't want to add Kuma as vendored dependency in my project.

Comment: Why do you want to include Kuma as a dependency in your project? It doesn't have any public APIs. Anyway, the `go mod` command ignores `replace` directives in dependent modules, and the version tag is non-existent so...

Comment: I want to use their policy models and validation logic in my project.

Comment: As mentioned by @rustyx there's no public api so it's tricky to use this as a dependency. Though I think you'd fix this by adding the replace in your own go.mod